# Not able to install npm, Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 20.04

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

Hi all I am trying to install npm after having installed nodejs but it gave me the following error "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." . If I install singularly npm I get the list of broken packages but when i use which I am not able to find nothing
[image]

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details which provide useful details; so we're somewhat limited & have to base on what you provided; ie. `node-gyp | 3.6.2-1ubuntu1 | bionic/universe  | source, all`  but without your release details we can't know how it fully relates...

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update` and try again?